# Cake.AppCenter: Could not locate executable

Tags: jenkins, visual-studio-app-center, cakebuild

Using iOS operating system.

While trying to publish the APK in MAC machine via Jenkins I am facing the below error,

```
Error: One or more errors occurred. (AppCenter: Could not locate 
executable.)
AppCenter: Could not locate executable.
```

I am facing this issue after upgrading my Visual Studio 2017 to Visual Studio 2019 with mono version **5.10.1** to **5.18.1**. Its working fine in previously with Visual Studio 2017 and 5.10.1 mono version. The issue is reproduced only after upgrading the Visual Studio and mono version.

Note: While I have to publish the APK manually from my machine its working fine. But when I try to publish via Jenkins, facing this error. **The issue can be reproduced only by calling the publish task (in cake file) from Jenkins.**

Could you please suggest a solution for this?

```
AppCenterDistributeRelease(new AppCenterDistributeReleaseSettings
{
    File =$"../Myapp.UWP/AppPackages/AppPackages_{revisionName}.app.zip",
    Token = apiToken,
    Group = "Collaborators",
    ReleaseNotesFile = "../cireports/releasenotes/releasenotes.txt",
    App = "My-Team/Myapp-Windows"
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need the [AppCenter CLI](https://github.com/Microsoft/appcenter-cli/) installed which is what the Cake.AppCenter addin orchestrates.

It's a node tool installable using `npm`

```
npm install -g appcenter-cli
```

Once installed, the `appcenter` command will be globally available.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have run this command in MAC terminal, some of the packages are installed and updated. But still have facing issue while publishing, I have getting this result  in terminal,
'sudo npm install -g appcenter-cli/usr/local/bin/appcenter -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appcenter-cli/bin/appcenter.js
npm WARN webpack-cli@3.3.6 requires a peer of webpack@4.x.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ appcenter-cli@2.0.0
updated 1 package in 23.523s'